# When changing php to fastcgi mode (php-fpm) under ubuntu20.04, the rewrite rule fails

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, fastcgi, rules

I have installed Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.4 on an Ubuntu 20.04 system. By default, PHP works in mod_php mode and the program's rewrite rule was functioning normally. However, when I switched to fastcgi mode, the program still worked in the background but the rewrite rule in the foreground became ineffective. Upon switching back to mod_php mode, the rewrite rule was restored to its normal state.

I have conducted research and found similar problems, but the solutions offered were mainly about installing mod_rewrite or modifying the rewrite rules. I have confirmed that the mod_rewrite module is installed and the rewrite rules in the .htaccess file are correct. I even tried another cloud server and encountered the same issue.

I am unable to resolve the problem and I am reaching out for help. If anyone has any insight, I would greatly appreciate it.

Note: I made no other changes to the system besides the switch to fastcgi mode for PHP.The following is the record of my operation command：

```
# Switch from mod_php mode to FastCGI
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif # Enable FastCGI mode.
$ sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm # Enable php-fpm.
$ sudo a2dismod php7.4 # Disable mod_php.
$ sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork # Disable prefork MPM.
$ sudo a2enmod mpm_event # Enable event MPM.
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2 #Restart apache.

# Switch back to mod_php from FastCGI:
$ sudo a2dismod proxy_fcgi setenvif # Disable FastCGI mode.
$ sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm # Disable php-fpm.
$ sudo a2enmod php7.4 # Enable mod_php.
$ sudo a2dismod mpm_event # Disable event MPM.
$ sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork # Enable prefork MPM.
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2 #Restart apache.
```

The command execution will return to normal at this time, but I still want php to enable fastcgi mode.